# Can you disable auxiliary/secondary routes in Angular?

Tags: angular, url-routing

I have a search field in my app, which, upon submission, navigates users to a URL like `myapp.com/search/my search phrase here`.

I have a route that handles this nicely:

```
{ path: 'search/:q', component: SearchResultsComponent }
```

The problem is, if people use parentheses in their search, like "hello (world)", the router crashes because it is looking for an auxiliary route/extra outlet being specified by the part inside the parentheses.

Is there a way to disable this functionality with the parentheses and just pass the full token to the component in the route?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't disable it, but you there is a workaround: encoding the percentage signs and then decoding them where you need to read the value.

```
// Add this somewhere
export const fixedEncodeURIComponent = (str: string) => {
  return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, (c) => {
    return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
  });
};


// In your component
this.router.navigate(['search', fixedEncodeURIComponent(query)]);
```